# Javascript call function with parameters in HTML using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In my html page i have this code:

```
onclick="javascript:CheckAdd({document.getElementById('user_btn').value,document.getElementById('txt_btn').value});
```

but when i click on button debugger say:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

what's wrong in my call?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an object to the `CheckAdd` function, this object must contain keys for each value:

```
onclick="CheckAdd({ key1: document.getElementById('user_btn').value, key2: document.getElementById('txt_btn').value });
```

Without the keys, your syntax is invalid.

However, if the `checkAdd` functions takes two argument and not an object, call it without the brackets, like this:

```
onclick="CheckAdd(document.getElementById('user_btn').value, document.getElementById('txt_btn').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add key.

```
onclick="javascript:CheckAdd({k1: document.getElementById('user_btn').value, k2: document.getElementById('txt_btn').value});
```

If you dont want to pass object pass an array.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `{ }` and try again or use a parameter like this

```
{v1:document.getElementById('user_btn').value,v1:document.getElementById('txt_btn').value }
```